# How to edit the data using contenteditable="true"

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I have written the code in angularjs.

where i am adding the data into the table using controller and ng-bind. but when i am trying to inline the edit current data it doesnt update in the controller.

```
 <div ng-controller="networkingSetupController">
        <div class="col-md-6"> 
            <label for="httpServer">HTTP Server : </label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addHttpServer" ng-model="addServerNames" />
                <div class="input-group-btn setPadding">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md pull-right" ng-click="addHTTPServer()">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 tableWrapper">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>HTTP Server Name</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="serverName in serverData track by $index">
                            <td ng-bind = "serverName" contenteditable="true"> </td>

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

controller code :-

```
 var app = angular.module('myapp', [])

        app.controller('networkingSetupController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.serverData = [];
            $scope.addHTTPServer = function () {
                console.log($scope.addServerNames);
                $scope.serverData.push($scope.addServerNames);
            }
        });
```

Thanx in advance

Plunker URL :- http://plnkr.co/edit/gW4xp6QTmVU1fDCoFQMQ?p=preview

Comment: I can't understand the problem.